# How to access a multidimensional hash session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, hash, hash-of-hashes

I am using the session method of Ruby on Rails so that I have a session[:user_params] hash like this:

```
password_confirmation: "test"
password: test
email: test@test.ij
```

I can access that simply using the syntax **session[:user_params]** in my view file.

Now I want access only the 'email' parameter, but trying to use **session[:user_params][:email]**, I get always an empty value. How to access this value?

Comment: I don't think that sessions support other values than strings, but I'm not sure. But storing too much information in a session is never a good thing. Try serializing your hash if you must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try `session[:user_params]['email']`. Off hand I'm not sure if Rails will serialize/deserialize the entire session hash as a HashWithIndifferentAccess or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are setting up the hash that you store in :user_params, but this is how I would do it and it seems to work:

```
puts "  email: '#{session[:user_params][:email]}'"

session[:user_params] ||= {}
session[:user_params][:password_confirmation] = "test"
session[:user_params][:password] = "test"
session[:user_params][:email] = "test@test.ij"
```

If you put this code inside a controller action the first time you will see '' for the email. The second time it will show 'test@test.ij' for the email. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help me. I want simply to show in my view file the email address using something like this: <%= session[:user_params][:email] %>.

Comment: After you have put the email into session from a controller then you can access it from the view with the code that you just posted: <%= session[:user_params][:email] %> .

Comment: What I was aiming for was <%= session[:pjt_user_params]["email"] %> which I think is the shortest/simplest way to get what I want.

Comment: If you are mixing :email and "email" as keys to the hash then that is probably why it doesn't work. Try evaluating :email == "email" from a rails console and you can see that they aren't equal. Try switching to use only :email. If that doesn't work post the rest of the code you are using and maybe there is something else.